# What are these magnetic LEGO-like bricks?

Tags: piece-information, clone-brands, vintage

Can anyone identify these? The tin they are in is dated around 1967 so bricks might be of a similar age. They are magnetic.
Any help greatly appreciated.

[image: magnetic bricks]

Answer (score 9):

According to [this article](https://brickset.com/article/92076/bricks-on-display-a-collection-of-interlocking-building-bricks#:%7E:text=of%20America%2C%20USA.-,Bombo%20Magnet%2D1963,-Bricks%20made%20of) these are called "Bombo Magnet".

> Bombo Magnet-1963.
> Bricks made of a metal plate with studs, a magnet, and its plastic cover. The plastic "grid" on the underside leaves exactly room for the elevations of the upper metal plate ensuring that bricks can be built precisely on top of each other. First presented at the 14th Toy Fair in Nuremberg. Made by: BOMBO GmbH in Bad Honnef am Rhein, Germany.

[image: bombo magnet]

[image: bombo magnet]

Comment: Amazing. Thankyou very much!